# How do I create and recall class objects from a resource file that I can use at runtime?

Tags: c#, resource-files

I am trying to create a resource file of message codes.  I've created a small console example that fails when I try to recall the object.

I based this on this [MSDN -Creating Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216(v=vs.100).aspx) example, but I don't know what I've missed while I tried to simplify it.

In the code I run it once to generate the resource file and add that file to the project. Then I recompile to run the recall code.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

namespace ResourceDemo
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      bool generateMode = false;

      if (generateMode) {
        // After running once with generate mode set to true, add the resulting
        // "StatusItem.resource" that was created in the .\bin\x86\Debug folder
        // to the project.
        Generate();
      }
      else {
        // When run the next line generates an exception:
        //   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
        //
        //   Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture
        //   or the neutral culture.  Make sure "StatusItems.resources" was correctly embedded or linked
        //   into assembly "ResourceDemo" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required
        //   are loadable and fully signed.

        StatusItem statusItem = GetResource("2");
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}  Message: {1}", statusItem.Id.ToString(), statusItem.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }

    public static void Generate()
    {
      StatusItem[] statusItem = new StatusItem[4];

      // Instantiate an Status object items.
      statusItem[0] = new StatusItem(2, "File not found");
      statusItem[1] = new StatusItem(3, "Path not found");
      statusItem[2] = new StatusItem(4, "Too many open files");
      statusItem[3] = new StatusItem(5, "File access denied");

      // Define a resource file named StatusItems.resx.
      using (System.Resources.ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(@".\StatusItems.resources")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          rw.AddResource(statusItem[i].Id.ToString(), statusItem[i]);
        }

        rw.Generate();
      }
    }

    public static StatusItem GetResource(string key)
    {
      Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("StatusItems", Assembly.Load("ResourceDemo"));

      return (StatusItem)rm.GetObject(key);
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class StatusItem
    {
      public StatusItem(int id, string message)
      {
        Id = id;
        Message = message;
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Message { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code successfully creates a non-embedded resource using the `ResourceWriter` and is able to recall the data objects using a dictionary.

It seems to work fine from the IDE. I tried to compile this at the command line but ran into some other issues that are better left to a separate question. I think it has more to do with comand-line compiling than the code.

I wanted to post something that answered this question specifically, though I will probably take the advice of Peter Duniho and use the `ResxResourceWriter` family instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Resources;

namespace ResourceDemo
{
  internal class Program
  {
    private const string nameSpace = "ResourceDemo";
    private const string resourceExtension = ".resources";
    private const string resourceFilename = "StatusItems";
    private static IDictionary<string, StatusItem> dictionary;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      bool generateMode = false;

      if (generateMode) {
        // Only run when a new resource is added
        Generate();
      }
      else {
        // Show the contents of the resource
        EnumerateResource();

        // Make a dictionary so it is usable
        BuildDictionary();

        Console.WriteLine("Look-up items 2, 4, 42 and 3 in dictionary");
        WriteStatusItemToConsole(GetResource("2"));
        WriteStatusItemToConsole(GetResource("4"));
        WriteStatusItemToConsole(GetResource("42"));
        WriteStatusItemToConsole(GetResource("3"));
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build the working dictionary from the resource file
    /// </summary>
    public static void BuildDictionary()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Building a look-up dictionary");
      StatusItem statusItem;
      dictionary = new Dictionary<string, StatusItem>();
      ResourceReader res = new ResourceReader(@".\" + resourceFilename + resourceExtension);

      IDictionaryEnumerator dict = res.GetEnumerator();
      while (dict.MoveNext()) {
        statusItem = (StatusItem)dict.Value;
        dictionary.Add(dict.Key.ToString(), statusItem);
      }
      res.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("{0} items written to dictionary.", dictionary.Count.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List all the items inside the resource file. Assuming that the
    /// </summary>
    public static void EnumerateResource()
    {
      StatusItem statusItem;
      Console.WriteLine("Resources in {0}", resourceFilename + resourceExtension);
      ResourceReader res = new ResourceReader(@".\" + resourceFilename + resourceExtension);
      IDictionaryEnumerator dict = res.GetEnumerator();
      Console.WriteLine("Dictionary Enumeration ready");
      while (dict.MoveNext()) {
        statusItem = (StatusItem)dict.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}: '{1}, {2}' (Type: {3})", dict.Key, statusItem.Id.ToString(), statusItem.Message, dict.Value.GetType().Name);
      }
      res.Close();
      Console.WriteLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to create the binary resource file. Needs to be called once.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Generate()
    {
      StatusItem[] statusItem = new StatusItem[4];

      // Instantiate some StatusItem objects.
      statusItem[0] = new StatusItem(2, "File not found");
      statusItem[1] = new StatusItem(3, "Path not found");
      statusItem[2] = new StatusItem(4, "Too many open files");
      statusItem[3] = new StatusItem(5, "File access denied");

      // Define a resource file named StatusItems.resx.
      using (System.Resources.ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter(@".\" + resourceFilename + resourceExtension)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          rw.AddResource(statusItem[i].Id.ToString(), statusItem[i]);
        }
        rw.Generate();
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Look up StatusItem in dictionary with the given key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static StatusItem GetResource(string key)
    {
      StatusItem result = null;
      if (dictionary != null) {
        dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result);
      }
      return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write the value of the given item to the console
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusItem"></param>
    public static void WriteStatusItemToConsole(StatusItem statusItem)
    {
      if (statusItem != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("   Id: {0}  Message: {1}", statusItem.Id, statusItem.Message);
      }
      else {
        Console.WriteLine("Null Item");
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is our sample class
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable()]
    public class StatusItem
    {
      public StatusItem(int id, string message)
      {
        Id = id;
        Message = message;
      }

      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Message { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> …and add that file to the project

How? Are you adding the file in the IDE? If so, that won't work...that treats the file as plain binary data; it's not interpreted as resource data itself. You need to use `/resource` on the command line or use `al.exe` to embed the .resource file after the fact.

If you want to be able to simply add the generated resources output to your project, you probably want to use `ResXResourceWriter` instead of `ResourceWriter`. Then you'll get a .resx file, which you *can* add to the project directly. Visual Studio will compile the .resx file into a .resources file and embed it correctly automatically.

This also has the advantage of producing a human-readable file, and one that can also be opened within the IDE (albeit with limited functionality, depending on the types you put into it).

Caveats:

- The `ResXResourceWriter` class is actually defined in `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, so you'll need to include a reference to that assembly in your project.
- Types you write to the .resx file will need to be able to be referenced at compile time, which means they can't be in the same assembly you're compiling. You'll need to put them in a separate DLL that is referenced by your program.
- The `ResourceManager` name for the .resx file will be fully-qualified in the context of your project. So for example, assuming you add the .resx file as a top-level file in your project, you'll need to load `"ResourceDemo.StatusItems"` instead of just `"StatusItems"`. If you add the .resx file "As a link", it will by default wind up in your project contained in folders corresponding to the file system, e.g. "bin\Debug\StatusItems.resx". In that case, the manager name will be `"ResourceDemo.bin.Debug.StatusItems"`.

Regarding that last point, if you ever have any question about the name, you can use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` to inspect what the names that have been compiled into your program are.

Comment: I simply added the existing item to the project.  I'm compiling in the ID, what command kine do I add the /resource option?

Comment: @Rich: You would need to compile your .cs file from the command line using csc.exe, providing the `/resource` switch for the .resources file you want to include. If you want to using the .resource file format and still include it as an Embedded Resource item in the project, then you would need to retrieve the item as raw data and the `ResourceReader` class yourself to actually read the data. Personally, I'd go with the .resx file option, as that provides the best integration into the normal resource-management mechanisms.

Comment: But if I use the ResXResourceWriter family I wouldn't have to do the extra steps?

Comment: @Rich: that's correct. If you use `ResxResourceWriter`, then you can add the .resx file to your project as you're trying to do now (it will still have the Build Action of "Embedded Resource"). The caveats I describe above apply of course; the one that is likely to be the most problematic is the requirement that types used in the resources are declared in a different assembly from where you are importing them. Whether that's really an issue in your situation depends on specifics you haven't described.